# Angular 4 setInterval unexpected behaivor

Tags: javascript, angular, setinterval

I have this issue with setInterval in an Angular 4 component. It seems like the scope is wrong and not updating the component as expected. I've read around that arrow functions are the solution to maintaining the scope here of the component.

It appears that the role is definitely set (results are updated in the template file as expected) and the setInterval does in fact stop running via what I assume is the call to clearInterval(). However, this.loadingActions which I'd like to be set to false (initialized as true) is not properly updated. If I debug in that block this.loadingActions member on the component is undefined whereas the console.log(this.loadingActions) prints false and the UI itself remains not updated.

roleSetup() is called via ngOnInit()

```
roleSetup() {
    this.fetchRole = setInterval(() => {
        this.role = this.userDataService.getUserModel().role;
    }, 1000)

    if (this.role !== "") {
        console.log("hullo");
        this.loadingActions = false;
        console.log(this.loadingActions);
        clearInterval(this.fetchRole);
        console.log(this);
        debugger;
    }

    console.log(this.loadingActions);
    console.log(this.role);

}
```

I've also tried something like this, which I know is improper but still no luck with the scope

```
this.fetchRole = setInterval(() => {
        this.role = this.userDataService.getUserModel().role;
        if(this.role !== "") {
            this.loadingActions = false;
        }
    }, 1000)

    if (this.role !== "") {
        clearInterval(this.fetchRole);
    }
    console.log(this.role);
    console.log(this.loadingActions);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what's happening is a timing issue.

`setInterval` [will run the passed function asynchronously](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval). Therefore, all your code after `setInterval` runs *before* the role is fetched, so the if statement checking if the role exists always evaluates to `false`.

The reason it updates in the template is because Angular uses [Zone.js](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/), which is a library that alerts Angular after **any** browser event is done executing. (If you know angular.js, you can think of it as a tool which runs a digest cycle automatically after the `setInterval`)

Without removing your polling for the role, you could simply move your logic into the `setInterval`. That way, once the role is loaded, you can update the `loadingActions` boolean.

```
roleSetup() {
    this.fetchRole = setInterval(() => {
        this.role = this.userDataService.getUserModel().role;
        if (this.role !== "") {
            this.loadingActions = false;
            clearInterval(this.fetchRole);
        }
    }, 1000)

}
```

But it would probably be better if you could update your `userDataService` to have a function which returns the role in terms of a promise:

```
roleSetup() {
    this.userDataService.getUserRole().then(role => {
        this.role = role;
        this.loadingActions = false;
    });
}
```

Without knowing how your application is loading the role, I don't know if this is possible, but it would certainly be cleaner if you could do it this way.

Comment: I do like this thought, thanks for the reply. I'll give it a try

Comment: @RunFranks525 if it works, please mark the answer as correct :-)